# How can I change the language on the ubisoft store in the Browser from French to Dutch?

Tags: ubisoft-store

I live in Flanders, in Belgium. I got linked a free game on the US version of the Ubisoft store, and when I opened the link, it asked me whether I wanted to go to the Belgian version of the store. I agreed, but it sent me to the French version of the store: https://store.ubi.com/fr/home. Usually it should first send me to a language select interstitial slide (usually 2, even) before it moves on. I managed to redeem the free game somehow, but I now want to browse the rest of the store in Dutch, because I'm Flemish and I I'd rather not have to deal with any more French than I really have to.

I know I can change the url and replace the fr with nl (and this time I ended up just caving and doing that), but I don't know if that would bring me to the Dutch version of the store from the Netherlands instead of the Dutch version from Belgium. Hell, I don't even know if the two stores are different. Also, url manipulation like that is something I'd rather avoid because of how finnicky it can be at time to guess what the url would be, and I'd prefer to use methods native to the website I'm visiting, such as a country or language select option.

So is there a native way to change the Ubisoft Store language, or country if that's what I need to change here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the store page they offer is based on the country they think you are coming from.  For example, if I open the French link in the question, it suggests a location change.
[image]

As far as language changing, this seems to be based on the country you end up using.  For example, the US store has a dropdown at the bottom of the page to switch between English and Spanish.
[image]

Likewise, the CA page has options for English and French.  However, this language selection is not on all versions, such as the mentioned FR link nor the [NL link](https://store.ubi.com/nl/home).

As for how to switch to the correct store page, there's doesn't seem to be a built-in method at the moment.  Best option is probably to use a search engine looking for "Ubisoft [COUNTRY / LANGUAGE] store", with country appearing to give better results.  As far as I can tell, there is no BE version of the store.